# Sending form in json to servlet and doing validation

Tags: java, json, servlets

So i have this form with user name and password. I need to convert the form data in json and send it to a servlet, unpack the data do the validation and return the result back in json format to the browser. At the browser end i need to unpack and show the result.

Okay, so far i have written code to generate a json object from the form and send it to the servlet. Now i need help in receiving it at the servlet end to do validation.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

<script>
function sendrequest()
{

    var fname= document.getElementById("Fname").value;
    var password= document.getElementById("pass").value;
    alert("inside function" + fname+" "+password);
    var jsonstring="{\"fname\":\""+fname+"\",\""+"password\":\""+password+"\"}";

    //var jsonstring='{"fname":'+fname+"\",\""+"password:"+password+"}';

    alert(" jsonstring " + jsonstring);
     document.getElementById("mesg").innerHTML=jsonstring;
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);

    $.ajax({
           url: 'Chk',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {jsons: obj},
           error: function() {
             document.getElementById("mesg").innerHTML="there is error";
           },
           dataType: 'text',//'json'
           success: function(data) {
                 document.getElementById("mesg").innerHTML="working";

               alert("working");
              document.getElementById("mesg").innerHTML=data;


           }

        });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
User name:<input type="text" id="Fname" name="Fname" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
Password:<input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>

<input type="button" value="fwd" onClick="sendrequest();"/>
<div id="mesg">252</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Servelet code :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String json = request.getParameter("jsons").toString();



         // 1. get received JSON data from request

    }
```

I have looked at many example not sure how to parse this. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use json parse library.
JSON Simple is usually using library for parsing json string.

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

If you want to find any other library,
visiting "http://www.json.org/" and find text java.

You can find other libraries.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to how to do it exactly. I feel like i'm missing something. Would love an example.

Comment: What is user problem? You didn't know using json parse library? You can find API for libraries in their sites.